# Can I use a N. American table saw in Europe

Tags: electrical

I have some 220v small shop equipment, table and band saws, planer and jointer, etc. and I'm thinking of shipping them to Spain (where we're moving). I realize that there's the issue of 60Hz versus 50Hz, but something tells me that it's not that simple. What do I need to know to overcome this?

Comment: What brand/models? What to the data plates on the equipment say? _Some_ devices _can_ be run on 120/240v and 50/60Hz, others cannot. I would think that motors tend to run into the "cannot" category, but supplying some additional info would help us help you.

Comment: If it's actually a 220V saw, congrats! It's _already_ at European spec. I'd bet it's actually 240V though (or nominal 230), as has been the N.A. standard since the McCarthy era. Yes, more detail, please. The question isn't answerable as it is. Also, please take the [tour].

Comment: Tried asking the mgr or reading the manual to see what the actual requirements are?

Comment: Are these high-end machines and in good condition?   I ask because even if you determine they will work acceptably, I recommend against paying to ship equipment that is old and/or wasn't that great to begin with.   The money is better spent on new.  These are large, heavy machines, there is bound to be an incremental shipping cost even if you're containerizing.

Comment: No, they're in perfect shape despite age.  Yes, we have a container going, and it might not be that cost prohibitive.  The issue is whether they will work without added issues.

Comment: It seems the 50Hz will be the deciding factor, if the machines are only for 60Hz.  There are frequency converters, but cost of converter plus shipping cost only you can decide on.  Might get lucky when you check their labels and find they are listed 50/60hz.

Comment: If you're going to get a frequency converter, you might as well install VFDs. They're going to be cheaper (larger market, available used) and then you'll have the fanciest table saw in your town.

Comment: [This](https://www.eng-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=1224) kind of suggests "no".   Not practical experience but a data point for you.

Comment: Leave (sell off) the 60 Hz motors here, get 50 Hz motors there. Works for most woodworking tools with a belt drive motor connection, which is most woodworking tools. 60 Hz motors tend to overheat on 50Hz, as well as running slower (so you might want new drive pulleys as well as the new motors in Spain.) If you happen to have (unlikely) 50/60 Hz marked motors, no need. Otherwise, that's your simplest solution to not having to buy all-new equipment in Spain. You might even have 3-phase power at your new house!

Comment: The suggestion from Ecnerwal gives you a glide path!  Use your equipment as-is for brief, light duty jobs, pay attention to performance and temperature, and prioritize upgrading motors where needed.   @Ecnerwal it should be the Answer, too bad the question was closed.