# Is it possible to change the voltage on a Dewalt DWE7491rs 10-inch table saw from 120V to 220V?

Tags: electrical

I just bought a Dewalt DWE7491rs 10-inch table saw which is 120V 60 hertz.  I am taking it with me to Fiji which is a 220V 50 hertz country.  Is it possible to change the wires on the motor so it will run on 220V 50hz?  It seems some people do this for larger power tools.  I can't find anything about it in the manual. Would changing the voltage also change the hertz? If I can't change the voltage, would a transformer be an acceptable solution and will it take into account the hertz change?  Thanks!

Comment: The Brits are accustomed to massive transformers that step down to 110, so these things exist. If you had a ton of 110 tools and really cheap shipping costs, it might be worth it.

Comment: Never take electrical equipment across oceans. That is just madness. Since you are in the Eurasian 230V/50 Hz side of the great oceans, buy your electrical gear there.   Australia, Europe, Asia, unfortunately not  Guam, Japan, Taiwan, nor the Philippines.

Answer (score 4):

According to page 6 of [the manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1639985/Dewalt-Dwe7491.html?page=6#manual), there are *NO* indications of being able to rewire the motor to run on anything other than 120v/60Hz.

Your best bet is to return the saw and get your money back, then buy a 220v/50Hz version when you get to Fiji.

Comment: Well, my woodworker friends in Fiji say that all the other brands available in Fiji only last about 6 months with moderate to heavy usage.  Dewalt is the only brand that seems to really last over time.  Looked into transformers that change voltage and frequency but they are super expensive, twice the cost of the table saw.  So if I can't rewire the motor (which might not change the frequency anyway), my only option is one that changes the voltage only.  From what I have learned from all your helpful links to articles is that the motor will run more slowly and cooling will be slowed.

Comment: That's entirely your prerogative to do so. You might not be able to purchase a specific brand (DeWalt) directly in Fiji, but may be able to find one that works on 220v/50Hz in a neighboring country. Self-importing one designed for the local power grid will probably give you a better cost return than misusing/abusing one designed to run on a different voltage/frequency. Again, though, the choice is all yours...

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the frequency by changing wires or a transformer.  It is better to look for a manual and see if it tells you anything.

A transformer will take care of the voltage and it is possible that the frequency will not make much difference.  The saw will rotate a tad slower.  Instead of 3600 rpm, it will be 3000rpm.

According to this [article on table saws](https://woodhandy.com/how-fast-does-a-table-saw-blade-spin/) it should be okay:

> I found in my study that most direct drive table saws typically spin their arbors between 3,000 and 4,000....

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use a transformer but there are issues with that.  See the comments under [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/288668/65210) and read [this article](https://www.eng-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=1224).

It may be possible to replace the entire motor if you can find a compatible 220V one.  But you cannot just rewire the existing one.

The cost of shipping and adapting your saw and accepting the issues with using a transformer, might not be much less than buying one locally or from Alibaba or wherever Fijians buy cheap gear (or whatever grade gear you want.)

Comment: Dewalt is definitely a step above Alibaba.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact. Agreed but OP can find the right price/quality point there.   For most things, buying high-quality at good US prices makes sense.  But the higher price of the DeWalt might be more reason to not abuse it with 50Hz power.